# Como cambiar el texto de un Botón en un fragment en Android

Tags: android

Necesito cambiar el `texto de un boton` de acuerdo a ciertas condiciones, pero esto dentro de un `Fragment`, pero cuando trato de hacer tengo error aquí:

```
mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);
```

alguien me podria decir como corregir esto.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
private boolean mConfigModeConsola;
private String modoConsola = "";

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    mSendText = view.findViewById(R.id.send_text);
    mHexBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hex_btn);

    mHexBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mConfigModeConsola == false) {
                mConfigModeConsola = true;
                modoConsola = "HEX";
                mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);
                mSendText.setText( "" );
             }
            else {
                mConfigModeConsola = false;
                modoConsola = "ASCII";
                mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);
                mSendText.setText( "" );
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Aquí el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve revisando ese código, las únicas cosas que no veo que están en tu pregunta es la declaración de el botón, y asumo que el otro id que recuperas es un `TextView`, por que no casteaste con `(TextView)` no se si lo es o no. Tampoco veo el constructor en blanco que requiere el `Fragment`, quizás no es muy relevante para este caso pero es importante que coloques la mayoría del código para recibir mejores respuestas. Acá esta la forma en que realice el ejemplo, funciona con normalidad, cambia el texto del botón cada vez que lo pulso sin problemas.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button g;
    private TextView ls;
    private boolean mConfigModeConsola;
    private String modoConsola = "";

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        g = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.boton);
        ls = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

        g.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!mConfigModeConsola) {
                    mConfigModeConsola = true;
                    modoConsola = "HEX";
                    g.setText(modoConsola);
                    ls.setText( "" );
                }
                else {
                    mConfigModeConsola = false;
                    modoConsola = "ASCII";
                    g.setText(modoConsola);
                    ls.setText( "" );
                }
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

}
```

Si esta igual a este y te sigue dando el mismo error, podria recomendarte hacer es:

**File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Puede que tengas el error por eso, también hacerle un Clean al proyecto `(Build > Clean Project)` y un rebuild `(Build > Rebuild Project)`, también sincronizar con `Gradle`.

Comment: `David Villegas` he hecho como tu dices pero el error se persiste

Comment: has realizado todas las actualizaciones del IDE?

Comment: He creado nuevamente otro proyecto, ahora si funciona, ya no hay error

Answer (score 0):

mHexBtn.setText(modoConsola);

modoConsola es un string o donde lo definiste?

Podrías poner el error que te sale?

Comment: Por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para hacer comentarios o pedir aclaraciones, lee [answer]

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: No me permitió comentar por eso lo hice modo de respuesta que pienso responder cuando el usuario me responda

Comment: modoConsola es definido como `String`, al inicio esta el error que sale

Comment: Donde defines los botones, es decir. Button mHexBtn;